# Facebook Thumbnail Image Has Correct URL, Old Image

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I am having trouble controlling the thumbnail image that appears when I link to my site from Facebook. It is a Wordpress site with a theme, and so I do not feel comfortable trying to edit the header to change the content URL for the og:image. Instead, I deleted the default image that was stored in the location and uploaded my own. When I use the Facebook debugger, it gives the correct link for the image--the one that now points to my custom image. Following the link takes me to my newly uploaded image. However, Facebook still displays the old image. I have read that using the debugger should clear Facebook's cache of my website. But the only thing I can think is that it must still be using an old cached version, since the image it displays is no longer available at the URL it is linking to.

Is there anything else that I need to do at this point, or is it just a waiting game until Facebook re-crawls my site?

I have looked at other related questions, but they all seem to be about trying to change the URL where Facebook looks for the image. In my case, it's looking in the right place, just not "seeing" what is there.

Edit: I tried just linking to my image from a simple HTML file with the below code, and that worked correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
<img border="0" src="MyURL.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The Facebook debugger displays the exact same URL but somehow comes up with the old image.

Comment: There a current bug report for this, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140

Comment: Thanks! It looks like people were able to fix it by adding tags specifying the size. So I guess I am going to have to figure our how to edit my header. Or wait for Facebook to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was not able to get Facebook to recognize that the image had changed. I think that this has to do with Facebook's security. It saved a copy of the old image fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php... And it seems that, so long as the URL remained the same, it couldn't be prompted to retrieve the new image. I just added a "2" at the end of the URL and added a new meta-tag to my header with that URL and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this.  I was getting the default image instead of the one set in Yoast due to Facebook caching  Changing the post URL did the trick.  I was using WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the image cache, you can enter your URL into Facebook Object Debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Then, the cache will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have read everywhere, but, as I mentioned, for some reason, it still uses the old image--even though the URL it gives points to the new image--despite the fact that I have run the debugger many many times now.

Comment: Is the image too small? If the image dimension is too small, Facebook will find the next image which fits the minimum required size (484x252px min). Read this: http://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/images-photos-facebook-sizes-dimensions-types

Comment: I created the image to be the exact same size as the default one that I replaced, which was 200px x 200px and worked just fine. I want the small image at the left, not the full-wide one. Also, I think that if that were the issue, it would give the URL of the image that it had chosen instead. That is not the case. It lists the URL of the image I want, but uses the old image, which is no longer stored at that location. The old image is still on my site, but in a completely different place and not tagged as og:image.

Comment: If the current image cannot be used, Facebook may use the old cached one.